# Different php_value open_basedir based on domain name in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, open-basedir

I want to limit access to files using **[PHP open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)** for multiple domains. Every domain sits in own directory, so I want prevent all domains PHP scripts from interfering with each other. How can I set different `open_basedir` path for every domain in single `.htaccess`?

***If it would be only 1 domain, it could look like this:***

```
# /hosting/domains/.htaccess
php_value open_basedir /hosting/domains/example.com/
```

Every user has `FTP` account limited to `/hosting/domains/example.com/`.
So, obviously, I can not put `.htaccess` into `/hosting/domains/example.com/.htaccess` as user would be able to change `.htaccess` content. So, there must be single `.htaccess` in `/hosting/domains/.htaccess` for all domains.

**This is how I imagine it, is something like this possible?**

```
# /hosting/domains/.htaccess
php_value open_basedir /hosting/domains/${current_domain}/
```

I am using: Apache 2.4, PHP 5.5

Comment: May be just add it to virtual host configuration?

Why it should be in .htaccess?

Comment: I am on shared hosting without access to httpd.conf. Can use .htaccess only.

Comment: Have you asked the support team of your shared hosting provider?

Answer (score 1):

You can set `open_basedir` into virtualhost, so users won't be able to edit or delete it, within `<Directory>` directive.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible. Every domain has to have specific `.htaccess` file because this file is settings per folder so there is no way to specify subfolder. And even this is possible then user can use his own `.htaccess` file to override settings.

On shared hosting is only one solution. One user account per domain.